Paypal Card Payment method
I know there are some Paypal Payment methods in Magento 2 that allows the customer to pay the payment by using card on the checkout without leaving the site or redirecting to the other page or paypal page.
I configured all of these :

Braintree
PayFlow Pro
Pro Payments

But I want to use just one method that doesn't have any monthly fees.
Please suggest me that and also give me the configurations with the live mode.

I believe no payment method is entirely free. Even if there are no monthly fees, transaction fees still apply.

So which charge lesser file? And this will be charge for every transaction on merchant side right?

Please review : https://www.forbes.com/advisor/business/accept-credit-card-payments-cheap/

I mean to say Any one available in the magento which one I should use?
